# Reducer Output Ordered by Value List Size

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

We are writing a MapReduce program and we are wondering how we could make the reducer generate the output ordered by the value list size.

I searched online and basically all the methods talked about secondary sort. However, given that Mappers don't know the final list size, they cannot directly form a composite key like most articles mentioned.

We came up with an idea but it seems not smart. After first M/R, we got `<K, list<V>>` pairs, and we could use `<list_size, Pair<K, List<V>>>` for a new M/R. Then it will be ordered by list_size.

Is there any way that we could use one M/R and achieve this? Since reducer starts after all mappers, all the `<K, list<V>>` pairs should be available and able to be sorted. It just seems so simple, and I believe there are some built-in library methods for this, which unfortunately we don't know.

Any hint will be appreciated :)

Comment: My opinion is you will need to do this with a second job, once you know how large the list is.

Comment: Not possible as you don't know list size in sorting phase. Even if you customize sort you need to reorder as it's already sorted by K.